# Is there any way to get log along with user ip address any operations in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB community server version(4.2.2) and shell version(3.6.3) the log details stored insert, update, find and all operations but I need log details along with ip address for the end-user who access the db and perform each operations with ip address

I need ip address who perform these operations

```
2020-01-08T11:45:44.402+0530 I COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.$cmd appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: listDatabases { listDatabases: 1.0, $db: "admin" }
```

```
db.adminCommand( {
   setParameter: 1,
   logComponentVerbosity: {
      verbosity: 1,
      query: {
         verbosity: 5
      },
      network:{
        verbosity: 5
      },
      storage: {
         verbosity: 1,
         journal: {
            verbosity: 1
         }
      }
   }
} )
```

thanks for the contributions

Comment: Where is your mongoDB hosted in ? Also version 4.3.6 - I'm not sure what 4.3.6 is, I thought 4.2 is latest, please check for latest version:: (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/) Is there a community one recently released just checking..

Comment: in our private cloud. and sorry server version is 4.2.2 and shell version is 3.6.3

Comment: Did you check :: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238007/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-a-history-of-the-remote-connections-to-the-mongodb-in